# How to fix Raspberry Pi hanging after start with 2 sound card controllers?

Tags: usb, audio, usb-power

I have a Rpi 3 using with two sound card controllers (CM108). Rpi always hang after start if I connect sound card controller via usb but if I disconnect when booting and connect after booting is finished I don't get hanging. Anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried a powered USB hub?

Comment: Already tried but still hang.

Comment: I have seen the a similar thing, I can boot, command line, but when gnome starts it hangs. I have plenty of power as my CM109B's are on my separately powered card. My hardware is currently configured so that I don't enable the CM108B's until after now starts, and it mostly works well. There are times that it get confused when I have concurrent audio audio streams. I think our problems may be related. Please let me know if you have any ideas or workarounds.